# CSS, how to centralize vertically? (only IE does not works)

Tags: css, browser

How to centralize vertically of a div??

In FF, chrome, opera, safari, I use this:

top: 50%;

And centralize, but IE stuck at top. Why? how to centralize vertically in IE?

Comment: Answer to *why* is: IE has problems with % when parent levels have no fixed size set to it. If you can set a fixed height on the parent element, then `top:50%` will also work in IE.

Answer (score 4):

Read this article and hopefully get enlightened.

[Vertical Centering With CSS](http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/)

It explains 5 methods to achieve vertical alignment.

Comment: Method 3 looked like a good simple and cross browser solution.

Answer (score 0):

Best link I've found on centering content is [here](http://www.pmob.co.uk/pob/hoz-vert-center.htm).

I've used it in a couple of sites and it works on all browsers.

Comment: The downside here is that they use some browser specific hacks to get it working in all browsers, which makes it difficult to understand and maintain as a developer/web-designer.

Answer (score 0):

A nice one here

[Vertical Centering in CSS - Example](http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/priklady/vertical-align-final-solution-en.html)

Comment: That one requires that height of the containing tag is set to a fixed value. IE has a problem when the container has not fixed value.